# How to play/start youtube video after clicking on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, click

I have an image and I want to start a youtube video only after I click the image. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Comment: Here is a post with a full working example: http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/08/21/triggering-a-youtube-video-from-clicking-a-button-image-and-replacing-when-ended/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at:

[Youtube API examples](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Examples)

the code will be something like this:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    $('img').click(function() { 
        ytPlayer.playVideo();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) JQuery event handler:

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
  $("#iframe")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Another approach - switch iframe SRC (URL) with "?autoplay=1" version.

```
<a href="#" id="clickMe">PLAY</a>

<iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/F0naUkyEkmM" 
            data-autoplay-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/F0naUkyEkmM?autoplay=1"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery("#clickMe").on('click',function(){
    var vi = jQuery("#iframe");
    vi.attr("src", vi.data("autoplay-src") );
});
```

Comment: With this approach, if you click "go back" in the browser, some mess happens

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you. Working fine for me.

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function () {
    $(".video")[0].src += "1";
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="trigger">Click</a>
        
<iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJX71gFz_do?autoplay=" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding autoplay=1 only seems to work the first time.  I am using a start/stop button and when i click it the first time, i add autoplay=1.  Then when i click it again I remove the autoplay=1.  That works fine.

but when i try to start it again (adding autoplay=1), it won't start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This appears to be a comment instead of a true solution. Please consider moving this to the comments section or post it as a question in its own right. In any case, have a nice day!