# Trying to play youtube video after a few seconds, even if image is not clicked

Tags: video, youtube, playback, seconds

The answer you have provided to this user here:
[How to play/start youtube video after clicking on an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406063/how-to-play-start-youtube-video-after-clicking-on-an-image?newreg=b3fcace61ac14c399f7d10e463d08f62)

It was the solution to my query, so I have the video in my website and on click of the image it plays, now I want also for the video to play after lets say 10 seconds even if user does not click on the image.

Here is the fiddle I have been using based on what you posted:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3GAy/150/

```
$("#video-player").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover-state');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover-state');
});

$("#video-player.click-to-play-video").click(function(){
    $('#head').css({"background-color":"black"});

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width : '640',
        height : '360',
        videoId : 'qlEUrEVqDbo',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 },
        events : {
            'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
});

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    //event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player.destroy();
        $('#head').css({"background-color":"#aaa"});
    }
}
```

Comment: This is asked based on this past question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406063/how-to-play-start-youtube-video-after-clicking-on-an-image?newreg=b3fcace61ac14c399f7d10e463d08f62

Comment: The correct answer and solution for me was from: Nate Flink